# Upper bound for the change of argument

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, functions, upper-lower-bounds

Hi I am trying to calculate the change of argument.
For example, if I want to calculate the change in argument of function F(s) along the horizontal line from a+it to b+it(suppose there is no zero of F(s) in this line) then
we can consider
$$\Im\int_{b}^{a}\frac{F'}{F}(\sigma+it)d\sigma$$
From here, lets say we don't know about the argument of function F, but we do know
the upper bound of F,say
$$\mid F(a+it)\mid\leq M , \mid F(b+it)\mid\leq M$$ .
Then can I calculate like this?
$$\Im\int_{b}^{a}\frac{F'}{F}(\sigma+it)d\sigma\leq\mid\int_{b}^{a}\frac{F'}{F}(\sigma+it)d\sigma\mid\leq\mid[\log F(s)]_{b+it}^{a+it}\mid\leq 2\log M$$

Comment: Your inequality deserves a "modulus" sign :  $|F(s)|\leq M$. Besides, on which domain is this inequality valid ? If it is on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$, and $F$ is holomorphic, $F$ will be a constant...

Comment: @JeanMarie My bad,Thank you for the corrections. I edited it. So can i ask that turning the change of argument to just normal integral would be okay??

Comment: Be very cautious  $\log Z = \log|Z|+i \theta$ (for a certain range of theta in order to remain with the same determination) $\implies   |\log Z| = \sqrt{\log|Z|^2 +\theta^2}$...

Comment: @JeanMarie oh i didn't think about the existence of $\theta$, thanks. Then if M is sufficently large, then can we bound the change of argument by C$\cdot$$\log$ M for some constant C.?(Since $\theta$ can be considered as some constant+2$\pi$n with some integral number n)

Comment: It looks so... Check on different functions like $\operatorname{atan}$ on a bounded region.

Comment: @JeanMarie I will check and be cautious about this kind of transition as your advice. Thank you, Sir!!